# Mock object creation inside a method

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, easymock

If I have the following method:

```
public void handleUser(String user) {

    User user = new User("Bob");
    Phone phone = userDao.getPhone(user);
    //something else
}
```

When I'm testing this with mocks using EasyMock, is there anyway I could test the User parameter I passing into my UserDao mock like this:

```
User user = new User("Bob");
EasyMock.expect(userDaoMock.getPhone(user)).andReturn(new Phone());
```

When I tried to run the above test, it complains about unexpected method call which I assume because the actualy User created in the method is not the same as the one I'm passing in...am I correct about that?

Or is the strictest way I could test the parameter I'm passing into UserDao is just:

```
EasyMock.expect(userDaoMock.getPhone(EasyMock.isA(User.class))).andReturn(new Phone());
```

Comment: Does your `User` class have an `equals` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that the unexpected method call is being thrown because the `User` object is different between the expected and actual calls to `getPhone`.

As @laurence-gonsalves mentions in the comment, if `User` has a useful `equals` method, you could use `EasyMock.eq(mockUser)` inside the expected call to `getPhone` which should check that it the two `User` object are equal.

Have a look at the [EasyMock Documentation](http://easymock.org/EasyMock3_0_Documentation.html), specifically in the section "Flexible Expectations with Argument Matchers".

Comment: So if I implement the equals method for User, could I then pass in my userMock, or will I have still have to use EasyMock.eq(mockUser) like you've suggested along with the implemented equals?

Comment: If the User equals method compares on the name (Bob), then creating the expected method via User mockUser = new User("Bob"); EasyMock.expect(userDaoMock.getPhone(EasyMock.eq(mockUser))).andReturn(new Phone()); should work

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
EasyMock.expect(userDaoMock.getPhone(EasyMock.anyObject())).andReturn(new Phone());
```

I think this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A little change in the answer given by Yeswanth Devisetty

`EasyMock.expect(userDaoMock.getPhone(EasyMock.anyObject(User.class))).andReturn(new Phone());`

This will solve the problem.